# Difference between curve_fit and leastsq in python from scipy.optimize

Tags: python, scipy, curve-fitting

I have a function containing:
Independent variable X, 
Dependent variable Y
Two fixed parameters a and b.

Using identical experimental data, both the `curve_fit` and `leastsq` functions could be fitted to the function with similar results.

Using `curve_fit` I have:
`[  2.50110215e-04 ,  7.80730380e-05]` for fixed parameters a and b.

Using `leastsq` I have:
`[  2.50110267e-04 ,  7.80730843e-05]` for fixed parameters a and b.

I would like to know if are there any differences in both of them, if so, what are the what situations should I use `curve_fit` and what situation should I use `leastsq`?

Comment: Please post the actual code you're running to get these results.

Answer (score 6):

`curve-fit` is using `leastsq` for the calculation, so they should always give the same result. The miniscule difference you see there is probably a result of rounding error somewhere. calling `leastsq` directly should eliminate that.

From the docs of [curve_fit](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html#scipy.optimize.curve_fit):

> The algorithm uses the Levenberg-Marquardt algorithm through leastsq.
>   Additional keyword arguments are passed directly to that algorithm.